# The pm2 run the python file errored

Tags: python, pm2, python-venv, serve

My server system is Debian. I use pm2 to manage the process. 
One of the processes is a python backend.
I have created a venv environment for it and activated it.  I use this command to change ownership of the directory.

```
sudo chown myuser /var/www/mybackendcode.
```

This is my command to start my pm2 process

```
pm2 start /var/www/mybackendcode/serve.py --interpreter "/var/www/mybackendcode/venv/bin/python3.8" --name HD-backend
```

It seems that the pm2 process can start successfully, but when I check the status again. The process showed errored.

I check the pm2 log of this process.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
26|HD-back |   File "/var/www/home_delicious/home_delicious_backend/serve.py", line 1, in <module>
26|HD-back |     import bjoern
26|HD-back | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bjoern'
```

This error message also appears when I run “python3.8 serve.py” to start the server directly. 
But when I use "sudo python3.8 serve.py”. the server can be started successfully.

What is the problem? and How can I fix it?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you installed pip already?, with that you can install any dependency like bjoern with "pip/pip3 install bjoern" and that's it  https://pypi.org/project/bjoern/

Comment: Yes, I have installed and I install bjoern and other libs using pip.  And I can use "sudo python3.8 serve.py" to start the server. So the guess if this is the problem of permission  to access python module?

Comment: if you use `sudo python3.8` to run it then use it also to install modules `sudo python3.8 -m pip install ...` because you may have many Pythons installed and `sudo python3.8` may run different Python than `pip/pip3` - but different Pythons don't share modules.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. So when I install the lib use `sudo` or nor is install different and they are not shared!